# Pre load background images in jQuery

Tags: jquery, preload

I'm having trouble pre loading background images. This is my attempt but still seems to not be working - ie. there is still a delay seeing the image when i call showAjaxLoader("#mytarget"). Does anybody have any suggestions?

CSS:

```
div.entryform-ajax-loader {
    background-image:url(../images/preloader-entry-form.gif);
}
```

Script:

```
var ajax_loader = $('<div />').attr('class', 'entryform-ajax-loader');

function showAjaxLoader(target)
{
    $(target).append(ajax_loader);
}

function hideAjaxLoader(target)
{
    ajax_loader.remove();
```

Comment: how is it not working? Is it throwing a javascript error or is it just not preloading the image?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained better, please see my question again I've edited it.....

Comment: Don't see any problem except the closing of "}"  for function hideAjaxLoader(target)

Comment: It's really going to be only an issue on the first load. Then for each successive load/use it will pull it from the local cache. Unless this is a massive file then it's not really that much of an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a div to your head which has the source as your image, in this case, image will be loaded before the actual page loads.

```
<div style="display:none">
<img src="../images/preloader-entry-form.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: Will this make the image load twice, if I use the same image later in the page?? Will it afffect page performance? or the image is loaded just once and then used from browser memory and so on?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:none">
<img src="../images/preloader-entry-form.gif">
</div>
```

In the head of page body or if you need JQuery solution

```
http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

As an altermative solution, you may add this script to your file,

```
$(function() {
$(document.body).append($("<img />").attr("src", "../images/preloader-entry-form.gif").hide())
});
```

which will load the image at the beginning of page load. As a result when the function showAjaxLoader will be executed, the image will be loaded without any delay.